# Different behaviour for tspan rotation with dy crossbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to place some text via `textPath`

```html
<svg id="svg1" style="overflow:visible;height:min-content">

  <path id="path1" stroke="black" d="M 0 50 L 100 50" stroke-width="10" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" >

    <textPath href="#path1" startOffset="50%" fill="red">
      <tspan dy="26" rotate="180" font-size="100">O</tspan>
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

But for some reason this same code gives different output for different browsers

for Brave:
[image]

for firefox:
[image]

How do I fix this so that it gives the same output regardless of which browser you use?

Comment: This is definitely a bug in the implementation of `<textPath>` by Chromium (its rendering engine is used by Brave). Rotation should always happen about the [current text position](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TermCurrentTextPosition). You can test that without a text path Chom/Brave renders the rotation the same as Firefox.